# Unable to Make Bootable USB Stick From ISO [repeated]

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, usb, iso-image

I want to do a duo SO in my computer so, I want to install first Windows and then Ubuntu to use the Linux Grub. The problem has arrived when I tried to do the `Win-'x' USB bootable`. I don't care about `win7` `win8` or `win10` but in all of them downloading the official ISO from microsoft I'm getting this error.

**At first I was using Unetbooting because my main computer (the one I want to do duo-partition) is ubuntu 16LTS** and after run the bootable... The installer was like... 'void' after select it it was just waiting the default way to run but it was an infinity loop.

After try like 7 times to create a `USB-Bootable` using the `win7 win8 and win10 ISO's`... I decided to use my my bro's computer and then using the oficial Microsoft tool to create bootable USB I received this error:

> Files copied successfully. However, we were unable to run bootsect to make the USB device bootable. If you need assistance with bootsect, please click the "Online Help" link above for more information.

**And I really need it... any idea?
Thanks you so much!**

Comment: Have you tried a different USB flash drive?

Comment: Yes I tried and differents officials ISO! @Argonauts I have read that the reason is because there is not bootsect.exe so, I'll try this afternoon

Comment: Are you trying to build a USB boot disk for a UEFI or legacy MBR based PC? It sounds like some of your attempts built ok but wouldn't boot while the others wouldn't build. Is that accurate? Bootsect.exe is, AFAIK, a legacy windows utility for rebuilding an mbr on bootable media. If you're drive has a GPT partition it would crash and burn like you are seeing. In any case if you can provide more specifics it would help.